# Prevent angular from creating unecessary dom element

Tags: angular

I defined a footer  : `<app-footer></app-footer>`

The app-footer template is : `<footer>[...]</footer>`

Hence, the generated DOM is : `<app-footer><footer>[...]</footer></app-footer>`

I want to keep `app-footer` in the code but I don't want it in the DOM. i.e. I want the DOM to only contain `<footer>[...]</footer>`.

How do I achieve that?

Comment: You could always change your selector from `app-footer` to `[app-footer]`, so that it becomes an attribute selector. Then, when you want to use it, instead of `<app-footer></app-footer>` you can do `<footer app-footer></footer>` and remove the footer tag from your `app-footer.component.html` file

Comment: @user184994 Works like a charm! You can post it as an answer then I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always change your selector from app-footer to `[app-footer]`, so that it becomes an attribute selector.

Then, when you want to use it, instead of `<app-footer></app-footer>` you can do `<footer app-footer></footer>`

Then, just remove the `footer` tag from your `app-footer.component.html` file